# Arm eabi v7a system image API 23 for Android N preview is missing in SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk

Only Intel Atom System images, why?
For other API arm eabi is present.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html

> Only x86 system images are currently supported with the Android
>   Emulator for the Android N Preview.